# sharedPrefrence get data only once flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

i am trying to get data to a screen by shared prefrences so i set data here on my login screen:

```
var displayName=jsondata["username"];
    SharedPreferences prefs=await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('displayName', displayName);
```

and getting this data on my drawer:

```
  String displayName="0";



  initState() {
   getData();
   super.initState();
  }
   getData() async {
   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   displayName=prefs.getString('displayName')?? "0";
   }
```

**it gets the data when i click on drawer button but when go back to main screen and re-enter in my drawer it gets value "0"  **[here is the demo of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAH3B.gif)

what is wrong?

and here is the code of the other screen which I move in between:

```
   late String displayName;
   getData() async {
   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  displayName=prefs.getString('displayName')?? "0";
 print(displayName);
}
initState() {
  getData();
  super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to below code

```
String displayName="0";



  initState() {
   getData();
   super.initState();
  }
   getData() async {
   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
if(displayName.isEmpty || displayName == "0"){
   displayName=prefs.getString('displayName')?? "0";
await prefs.reload();
}
   }
```

Comment: The operand can't be null, so the condition is always false. (Documentation)  Try removing the condition, an enclosing condition, or the whole conditional statement.

Comment: Please check updated code

Comment: it still gives me zero .. i want to get name always .

Answer (score 1):

first of all always use a method after `super.initState();` inside `initState`.
after that **assuming that variable `displayName` is not updated anywhere else** try to `log` when ever `displayName` changes in your code.
I can see that another screen is opening and then he value changes. so please show us more code of what you write.

Comment: i updated the code please check.

Answer (score 0):

to Keep listening to code even you moved between pages,use StreamBuilder

```
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                    stream:getData(),
                    builder: ( context, snapshot) {
                      if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.waiting){
                        return CircularProgressIndicator();
                      }else {

                        if(snapshot.hasData){
                       // .......

                        }
                       

                      }
                    }
                )
```